# Convert string from codepage 1252 to 1250 and back

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I work with Delphi 7 (ANSI based). I need to convert strings between code pages. I found a solution on the net with multiByteToWideChar and wideCharToMultiByte functions. But as I see it does not work back and force. I can convert from 1250 to 1252 but the other way is not so nice.
Here is my test code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

function ANSIToUTF8( text_ : string; codePage_ : cardinal ): string;
var
  w : WideString;
  sizeMB, sizeWC : integer;
begin
  if ( codePage_ <> CONST_codepage_UTF8 ) then
  begin
    // ANSI_XXXX to UTF16
    sizeMB := length( text_ );
    sizeWC := multiByteToWideChar( codePage_, 0, PAnsiChar( text_ ), sizeMB, nil, 0 );
    setLength( w, sizeWC );
    multiByteToWideChar( codePage_, 0, PAnsiChar( text_ ), sizeMB, PWideChar( w ), sizeWC );

    // UTF16 to UTF8
    sizeMB := wideCharToMultiByte( CONST_codepage_UTF8, 0, PWideChar( w ), sizeWC, nil, 0, nil, nil );
    setLength( result, sizeMB );
    wideCharToMultiByte( CONST_codepage_UTF8, 0, PWideChar( w ), sizeWC, PAnsiChar( Result ), sizeMB, nil, nil );
  end else
    result := text_;
end;

function UTF8ToANSI( text_ : string; codePage_ : cardinal ): string;
var
  w : WideString;
  sizeMB, sizeWC : integer;
begin
  if ( codePage_ <> CONST_codepage_UTF8 ) then
  begin
    // UTF8 to UTF16
    sizeMB := length( text_ );
    sizeWC := multiByteToWideChar( CONST_codepage_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar( text_ ), sizeMB, nil, 0 );
    setLength( w, sizeWC );
    multiByteToWideChar( CONST_codepage_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar( text_ ), sizeMB, PWideChar( w ), sizeWC );

    // UTF16 to ANSI_XXXX
    sizeMB := wideCharToMultiByte( codePage_, 0, PWideChar( w ), sizeWC, nil, 0, nil, nil );
    setLength( result, sizeMB );
    wideCharToMultiByte( codePage_, 0, PWideChar( w ), sizeWC, PAnsiChar( Result ), sizeMB, nil, nil );
  end else
    result := text_;
end;

  procedure testString( s_ : string; icp_ : cardinal );
  var
    sutf : string;
    s1250, s1252 : string;
    pc : pchar;

    function strToHex( s_ : string; ocp_ : cardinal ) : string;
    var
      i : integer;
    begin
      result := '';
      for i := 1 to length( s_ ) do
      begin
        if ( i > 1 ) then
          result := result + ', ';
        result := result + TStringUtility.byteToHexaDecimalStr( ord( s_[i] ) );
      end;
    end;

    procedure logInput;
    var
      s : string;
    begin
      s := 'Input (' + intToStr( icp_ ) + '): ' + strToHex( s_, icp_ );
      listbox1.items.add( s );
    end;

    procedure logOutput( ocp_ : cardinal );
    var
      s : string;
    begin
      s_ := utf8toansi( sutf, ocp_ );
      s := 'Output (' + intToStr( ocp_ ) + '): ' + strToHex( s_, ocp_ );
      listbox1.items.add( s );
    end;

  begin
    logInput;
    sutf := ansitoutf8( s_, icp_ );
    logOutput( 1250 );
    logOutput( 1252 );
    listbox1.items.add( '' );
  end;

begin
  testString( #$f5 + #$fa + #$fb, 1250 ); // õúû in 1250
  testString( #$6f + #$fa + #$75, 1252 ); // õúû in 1252
end;
```

---

The logged results are not the expeted ones. It shows that the api calls converts the strings from 1250 into 1252 but no 1252 to 1250. I changed my default code page to 1252 and the result was the same.

```
Input (1250): $f5, $fa, $fb
Output (1250): $f5, $fa, $fb
Output (1252): $6f, $fa, $75

Input (1252): $6f, $fa, $75
Output (1250): $6f, $fa, $75
Output (1252): $6f, $fa, $75
```

Comment: This was solved decades ago by the introduction of Unicode.

Comment: FWIW, `#$6F` and `#$75` are plain ASCII, which is probably the same in all encodings. But the code points encoded with `#$F5` and `#$FB` don't seem to exist in 1252, so they become plain ASCII values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are attempting is not possible. There are characters in 1250 that are not present in 1252, and vice versa.

Consider the example characters from your question. Let's start with `$f5` in 1250. That is `ő`. Now, that character does not exist in 1252, and so the system has no way to do what you ask it to do. Instead it does the best it can, and returns `$6f` in 1252 which is `o`.

Then when you convert back from 1252 to 1250, there's no problem, because `o` is in the ASCII range and can be converted correctly. But of course there's no way for the system to be able to get back to `ő`, that information was lost when you went to 1252.

If you need to handle text in either 1250 or 1252, then the obvious solution is to use Unicode.

Comment: I have to get RTF content from RichEdit and it store the text content in ANSI :( The code page marked at the header by ansicpg.

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. I answered the question that you asked. What you are trying to do, as expressed in your question is simply impossible. What made you decide that ANSI was the way forward. Why are you rejecting using Unicode as I suggest in the final paragraph?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But... as I can see the 1252 -> 1250 convertion fails (the output char codes are the same in that way)

Comment: No. It's as I explain in my answer. `ő` exists in 1250, but not 1252. So once you convert to 1252, an `o` is substituted. That's the point where the information is lost. Do you understand that 1250 (and indeed 1252) have just 256 code points? You appear to be hoping to be able to hold greater than 256 different values in a 8 bit type. Given your name is *bitman*, that feels mildy ironic if you don't mind me saying.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you! By that time I strongly thought $f5,$fa and $fb under 256... :)

Comment: They are under 256. `$ff = 255`. All code points in an ANSI code page are in the range `0..255`, or `$00..$ff` when expressed as hex.

Comment: I know that very well. IT was ironic ;) As I can know the base ANSI codes are under 128 (7 bits). The greater values (128..255) are code page specific ones. But all of the codes are one byte long. UTF char size depent on this 8th bit state, UTF16 chars are always 2 bytes long.

Comment: bitman, look at it this way: if all possible code points could be held in 8 bits, there would be no need for different code pages. This means that codepages only hold a limited subset of all possible code points, and if a "character" is not present in another code page, often a similar character is chosen, e.g. one without accents but same base character, in this case `#$F5` (o double accent aigu) in 1250 is converted to a simple `'o'` (no accent, plain ASCII) in 1252.